# WCF with spring

Tags: wcf, spring.net

I'm fairly new to wcf (we have yet to upgrade to .net 3.0 in my workplace) and I'm working on a little home project to bring myself up to speed with some of the 'newer' features of .net.

I tend to use spring.net in most of my projects and so after creating my first WCF service I started to look at configuration via spring.net

So far my service is configured via spring (I'm injecting objects into it) however I would like to avoid adding attributes to the service contract interface i.e. I would prefer to not have to add [ServiceContract] and [OperationContract] attributes to what should be a pono interface.

Is this possible with spring.net out of the box?

Answer (score 0):

According to the reference manual it should be possible [Chapter 28.5](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/wcf.html#d4e8157)

Comment: Indeed, but I've run into issues with this as illustrated in this topic: http://forum.springframework.net/showthread.php?t=5298 . I just add the attributes for now.

Comment: Well...I **almost** got it working.... http://forum.springframework.net/showthread.php?t=6396